# how to access activity which layout is included in navigation drawer activity layout

Tags: android, android-layout

i am developing app which has navigation drawer activity and i included the maps activity layout in the navigation activity's content_activity layout like be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.wowoni.bikesharing.bicyclesharing.activity.HomeActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">
<include layout="@layout/activity_maps"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

but i don't know how to access the map activity from navigation drawer?

Comment: when you create the navigation activity you will get more then one layout files check your layout folder.

Comment: Your question is not clear?

Comment: i want to access the map in the navigation drawer activity, so i create the google map activity and included it in the content layout file which is created when we create the navigation drawer but how can i access the maps activity means how can i take control on maps activity?

Comment: someone please replay me....

Comment: Is there anyone who can solve my problem,please replay here